# Angular - Getting JSON data as undefined

Tags: angularjs, http, get

I'm trying to retrieve json data using Angular $http.get. But I'm getting undefined for the value.

My Json File is as below

```
[
    {
        "BannerText": "The First Mobile SSP. Truly Optimized for Outstream Video",
        "IntroText": "Chololate SSO provides necessary infrastructure for app monetization thgough video ads. More than 150 million people worldwide see a Chocolage SSP ad each month.",
        "SolutionHeaderText": "Solution For Publishers",
        "SolutionValueText": "Unlock the true potential of your mobile inventory with industry leading eCPMs & Fill Rates"
    }
]
```

Script File

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    alert('Called');
      $http.get("data/homeData.json")
        .success(function(data) {
          $scope.details = data;
          alert($scope.details.BannerText);
        });
    });
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
    <div class="banner-section">
        <div class="banner-text text-center">
            <p>{{ details.BannerText }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your JSON like this,

> {
>           "BannerText": "The First Mobile SSP. Truly Optimized for Outstream Video",
>           "IntroText": "Chololate SSO provides necessary infrastructure for app monetization thgough video ads. More than 150 million people
>   worldwide see a Chocolage SSP ad each month.",
>           "SolutionHeaderText": "Solution For Publishers",
>           "SolutionValueText": "Unlock the true potential of your mobile inventory with industry leading eCPMs & Fill Rates"
>       }

```
 <body ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='HomeCtrl'>
    <h1>Read Json from file </h1>
    {{entities.BannerText}}   </body>
```

Here is the working [`App`](https://plnkr.co/edit/ANwYd0s1tUz5X4FdfXFD?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You have a valid JSON and JSON provided by @Sajeetharan also is correct.

If you want to use your JSON only then change data as below:

```
$scope.details = data[0];     // As it is an array so it should be in [0]
```

It will resolve your issue.